# Android Studio load different file from file system and it change strange format

Tags: android, android-studio

Below is my project loaded by Android Studio. What I have is install windows update while building project. After computer reboot, I open Android Studio and got this. Please help.

[image]

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart

Comment: thanks, I just done with clear source and git reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Don't panic, your project is not gone. I had the same issue and was about to scream but after opening the files in another editor, I saw they are just fine.

Simply click **File** -> **Invalidate Caches / Restart...** and wait for the android studio to do a clean build.

Its okay buddy.

Comment: I was try to invalidate and restart for several times. It's not fixed. So I remove the source and do git reverse. it's OK for now